# How to add space between \cline and \hline in tabular

Tags: tables

How can I add a little bit of vertical space between trimmed horizontal and the horizontal line created by `\cline{2-4}` and `\hline`, respectively.

A minimal (not) working example is:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\cline{2-4}
& a     & b  & c   \rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\\ \cline{2-4} \hline
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Min} & 1 & 5 & 6  \rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\\
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{Max} & 2  & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

In the example above, the lines created by `\cline{2-4}` and `\hline` overlay each other.

Comment: You can use `\noalign{\vspace{0.5ex}}` (or whichever value  looks best).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution with `\noalign` in practice:

```
    \documentclass{article}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{llll}
    \cline{2-4}
    & a & b & c \rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\\ \cline{2-4}\noalign{\vspace{0.25ex}} \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Min} & 1 & 5 & 6 \rule{0pt}{2.6ex}\\
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Max} & 2 & 4 & 5 \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]